# Writing init function for C struct

Tags: c, struct

So this is my struct in a header file:

```
struct _Variable {
    char *variableName;
    char *arrayOfElements;
    int32_t address;
};
typedef struct _Variable Variable;
```

and here is my implementation of the init function in .c file:

```
void initVariable(Variable *variable, char *variableName, char *arrayOfElements,
        int32_t address) {
    int lengthOfVariableNameWithTerminatingChar = strlen(variableName) + 1;
    variable->variableName = malloc(
            sizeof(char) * lengthOfVariableNameWithTerminatingChar);
    strncpy(variable->variableName, variableName,
            lengthOfVariableNameWithTerminatingChar);

    int lengthOfArrayOfElementsWithTerminatingChar = strlen(arrayOfElements)
            + 1;
    variable->arrayOfElements = malloc(
            sizeof(char) * lengthOfArrayOfElementsWithTerminatingChar);
    strncpy(variable->arrayOfElements, arrayOfElements,
                lengthOfArrayOfElementsWithTerminatingChar);

    variable->address = address;
}
```

I get no errors when I compile but when I run my test file:

```
void test_initVariable() {
    printf("\n---------------test_initVariable()-----------------\n");
    // TODO:
    Variable *variable1;
    initVariable(variable1, "variable1", "1, 2, 3", 4); // <== Causes binary .exe file to not work
}
```

Can anyone tell me how to fix my implementation?

Comment: Where do you think the uninitialized pointer points? There are already dozens of questions regarding the exact same issue.

Comment: "Causes binary file not to work"? Are you getting an error message?

Comment: Create a variable and pass a pointer to the variable to the initializer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Variable *variable1;
```

gives you an uninitialised pointer.  You don't own the memory it points to so can't safely write to it.

You need to allocate storage for `variable1`

```
Variable variable1;
initVariable(&variable1, "variable1", "1, 2, 3", 4);
```

would work.

If you want `variable1` to be dynamically allocated, it'd be easiest to have `initVariable` handle this

```
Variable* initVariable(char *variableName, char *arrayOfElements, int32_t address)
{
    Variable* var = malloc(sizeof(*var));
    if (var != NULL) {
        var->variableName = strdup(variableName);
        var->arrayOfElements = strdup(arrayOfElements);
        var->address = address;
    }
    return var;
}
```

Note that I've also simplified allocation/population of strings here.  Your code works but if you're using a posix-compatible system, [strdup](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strdup) is a much simpler way to achieve the same results.

As discussed in comments, you don't need to allocate storage if the string members of `Variable` will all be [string literals](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal).  In this case, you could simplify things to

```
Variable* initVariable(char *variableName, char *arrayOfElements, int32_t address)
{
    Variable* var = malloc(sizeof(*var));
    if (var != NULL) {
        var->variableName = variableName;
        var->arrayOfElements = arrayOfElements;
        var->address = address;
    }
    return var;
}
```

Comment: Don't you have to allocate memory for the strings?

Comment: @BitFiddlingCodeMonkey Yes.  That is already handled by `initVariable`

Comment: @BitFiddlingCodeMonkey That depends. In this example, you don't (string literals have static storage duration and they already have storage allocated for them).

Comment: @simonc It's not even necessary if you are working with string literals. Or who knows? We can't tell unless OP says something about ownership.

Comment: @H2CO3 I was assuming the question was about whether to allocate memory for strings inside `Variable`.  I agree this wouldn't be necessary for string literals but had thought it better not to limit the solution to this.  I'll add a note of a simpler solution for string literals if you think that'd help.

Comment: @simonc This answer is fine, just saying. (And pointing to OP and looking nasty for not having provided the necessary details...)

Answer (score 0):

You should pass `&variable1` to your method. Operator `&` will take the address of your struct and that is what you need to assign to the pointer on `variable`.

Use:

```
Variable var1;
```

And then call the method:

```
initVariable(&var1, "variable1", "1, 2, 3", 4);
```